# How do I populate a combobox with the name(s) of a worksheet as the result of a date selection?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have 2 comboboxes.  The 1st combobox (CboReviewDate) holds dates.  The 2nd combobox (CboReviewModule) will be populated with the names of all the worksheets in the active workbook (if they contain a date in column "x" that matches the date selected in CboReviewDate).

I need help setting up the logic and choosing the correct search tool.
Will this logic flow work?
Will the loop routine erase the existing entry in CboReviewModule?

This is a learning process for me, so I would like to develop the code myself.  Please just point me in the right direction.

Here is my pseudocode:

```
'Run on "CboReviewDate"_change state
'CountIf (date in column "x" = "CboReviewDate.Value") in worksheet 1 of active workbook
'if result <> 0 then pass name of worksheet to variable "a"
'.additem to "CboReviewModule" using value of variable "a"
'reset value of variable "a" and loop until all worksheets in active workbook have been searched
```

Comment: The details you provide should show the code you use to populate the comboboxes, and should give some indication as to what range and worksheets the data is located in, you haven't provided any of that.

Comment: I understand that I didn't provide any code for review.  Is there a better way to phrase my question in order to get feedback about my methodology, rather than my code?  The type of answer I'm seeking if in the form of:  "No, you should use the Count function rather than the Countif function, for reasons x,y,z."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so here's me pointing you in the right/possible/some? direction.

- The first combobox should trigger a `Change` event when you select a date
- On that event you should map a procedure, that would
- A) Cycle all the worksheets (`Workbook.Worksheets` collection)
- B) Check each `Worksheet` for the date in Column X
- C) How you do the checking is up to you, you may wish to experiment with `Find` method of object `Range` (record macro for `Ctrl+F` and see how it works), but be careful about the error handling (when match is not found)
- D) If the date is found, `Worksheet.Name` is added to the item collection of your first combobox.

Comment: Thank you Marek.  I now have a pile of keywords to begin searching.  Off to do some research.  *zip*

Comment: @IsaacRothstein Come back with your results, we can have another look at it.

Comment: I've been able to make progress towards a solution.  I've gotten as far as performing the search and generating the results.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947244/how-do-i-get-vba-loop-result-to-populate-a-combobox