# Range.Find method to return first occurance of search

Tags: vba, excel, methods, combobox

In a previous bit of code, I ran a Range.Find method to return the names of all worksheets which had a specific date found in a specific column. "[How do I get vba loop result to populate a combobox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947244/how-do-i-get-vba-loop-result-to-populate-a-combobox)" Those worksheet names were then used to populate a combobox (CboReviewModule).  In this subroutine, a want the user to select one of the worksheet names from this combobox.  When that selection is made, I want the Range.Find method to run in Column 40 of the selected worksheet, find the first occurance of the date value saved in variable (myDate), then set the cell to Activecell.  After that, I'm using .offset to populate a series of textboxes with the values of all cells located to the left of the Activecell.

I cannot figure out how to make the Range.Find method return a positive result.  This following code is the latest iteration of many failed attempts:

```
Private Sub CboReviewModule_Change()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsName As String
Dim myDate As Date
Dim rngFind As Range
Dim firstAddress As String
Dim iCount As Integer
Dim myArray(38) As Variant

    'Set date variable equal to value of combobox selection
        myDate = Me.CboReviewWeek.Value
        'MsgBox (myDate) '{test successful}

    'Set ws name variable equal to value of combobox
        wsName = Me.CboReviewModule.Value
        'MsgBox (wsName) '{test successful}

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)

    'Run Find command on defined range and save result to range variable
    Set rngFind = .Columns(40).Find(What:=myDate, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row



'***** Add line to clear CboReviewModule each time the CboReviewWeek is changed. ***** _
****** Once a module is found on the selected date, the module Cbo won't clear when choosing a new date. *****



        'If cell is empty, loop to next row, if cell value matches myDate _
then pass cell address value to string variable
        If rngFind Is Nothing Then
            GoTo myNext
        ElseIf rngFind = myDate Then

     Do  'do this thing

    'set values of array by cell contents to the left of active cell
    myArray(0) = ActiveCell.Offset(, -39).Value
    myArray(1) = ActiveCell.Offset(, -38).Value
    myArray(2) = ActiveCell.Offset(, -37).Value
    myArray(3) = ActiveCell.Offset(, -36).Value
    myArray(4) = ActiveCell.Offset(, -35).Value

'and so on

    'populate values of userform cells based on contents of array
    Me.TxtAccount.Value = myArray(0)
    Me.TxtMR.Value = myArray(1)
    Me.TxtName.Value = myArray(2)
    Me.TxtType.Value = myArray(3)
    Me.TxtFinClass.Value = myArray(4)

 Loop While rngFind.Address <> firstAddress And Not rngFind Is Nothing

        End If
    End With

myNext:

    Next Cell
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to find a specific date in column **40**:

```
Sub FindingChristmas()
   Dim myDate As Date, r As Range
   Dim colmn40 As Range
   Set colmn40 = Range("AN:AN")
   myDate = DateSerial(2014, 12, 25)

   Set r = colmn40.Find(What:=myDate, After:=colmn40(1))
   r.Select
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> find the first occurance of the date value saved in variable (myDate), then set the cell to Activecell. After that, I'm using .offset to populate a series of textboxes with the values of all cells located to the left of the Activecell.

Your code for `.Find` is correct. However you are using the later part incorrectly. Replace the `ActiveCell` with `rngFind`

Try this

```
Set rngFind = .Columns(40).Find(What:=mydate, _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False).Row

If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
    myArray(0) = rngFind.Offset(, -39).Value
    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
End If
```